# StreamWriter to Reference Type

Tags: c#

Persisting a reference type with the StreamWriter is easy enough. And retrieving this data back into a string is easy as well, with the StreamReader.

But how can i convert the string the StreamReader returns into my custom reference type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persisting reference types (objects of classes) is called serialization. Reverse process is called deserialization. Both can be done easily in .net using [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

```
  XmlSerializer serializer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));
  OrderedItem item = new OrderedItem();
  //do stuff
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
     serializer.Serialize(sw, item);
```

reverse

```
  XmlSerializer serializer =  new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));
  OrderedItem item = null;
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
     item = (OrderedItem)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
```